# urls containing the # signal at the end

Tags: html, url, hashtag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [url having #! How is it useful For example facebook has www.facebook.com/#!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847844/url-having-how-is-it-useful-for-example-facebook-has-http-www-facebook-com)

Can someone explain the meaning of the # at the end of some url addresses? (twitter for example) Is it a convention for something?

EDIT: I want to clarify that I'm talking about using a # at the END of an url

Answer (score 3):

It's a reference to a "named anchor" - a link on a particular part of the page.  If you have `<a name="foo">` on a page then visiting `.../page.htm#foo` will take you to that place on the page.

If you're already on that page and the named link doesn't exist then visiting that anchor will just leave you where you are.

AJAX-based applications take advantage of that fact to store extra state information.  Any time Javascript code changes `document.location.hash` it creates a new browser history entry, but doesn't cause a page reload.  The JS code can listen for changes to that property and update their state based on its contents.

Comment: And if I'm seeing a "#" without anything after it? for example twitter.com/#

Comment: that'll just take you to the top of that page

Comment: So why is it added by default to some sites?